# Split a serial port device into two virtual COM's but with another app in the middle that controls data flow

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port, emulation, terminal-emulator

Good day,

As the title says.
Split a serial port device into two virtual COM's but with another app in the middle that controls data flow.

So i have this project and is my first time bumping into something like this. I have two Applications lets name them (Apple and Tomato) that have to use the same physical device, lets call this device COM1.
Now problem is that on Windows you can't have two applications using the same COM Port, so i thought ok lets split COM1 into COM10 and COM11 using a third party app.
Everything worked well until i saw that they tried to read and write information and physical device wen't crazy and could't understand what is going on and same for Apple and Tomato. So i'm stuck.

New idea and here i need some help with info and some code examples, case studies, whatever you guys can help with is appreciated.

Idea is to emulate physical device COM1 and tell Apple that he has a device and Tomato that he has another device, just like above, but only this time i would control the information sent to the real physical device over my emulator.

Comment: Given the lack of information, I can tell you we are using http://com0com.sourceforge.net/ which is opensource in order to do the COM pairs. AFAIK you will need two pairs, one for Apple and your middle program, and one for Tomato and your middle program.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to simulate a port forwarding feature that is used often in Ethernet.  Where multiple ports are combined onto a single hardware interface and then later split.  To be able to accomplish this in a serial port you need to add a header to each message indicating the original port number.  Then when the message is receive read the header and send to the appropriate channel.